# Is the following $(N+2)\times (N+2)$ matrix invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I wish to invert the matrix below, blank entries are $0$ (unless they fall into the obvious pattern).

$$B_h=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{h} & -\frac{1}{h} & 0 & 0 & \cdots &  \\
-\frac{1}{h^2} & \frac{2}{h^2} + c(x_1) & \frac{-1}{h^2} & 0 & \cdots & \\
0 & -\frac{1}{h^2} & \frac{2}{h^2} + c(x_2) & \frac{-1}{h^2} & \cdots & & \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \\
 & & & & &-\frac{1}{h^2} & \frac{2}{h^2} + c(x_N) & \frac{-1}{h^2} \\ 
&  & & & & 0 & -\frac{1}{h} & \frac{1}{h} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $h$ is sufficiently small and $c(x)$ is a strictly positive function.

I know this is a very messy way for displaying a matrix :(, but I want to show that this matrix is invertible. I'm thinking of proving that its kernel is the trivial kernel, so solving $B_hV$ $=$ $0$ to get $V=0$. However due to the big dimensions of this matrix I found it somehow difficult to solve such a system, also I think due to the presence of $c(x)$, only the zero vector satisfies this, but I know this is not an answer. Help me please :)

Comment: You can try to show that the determinant is nonzero via the Leibniz rule. This should be doable since the matrix is "almost" triangular.